# Cannot create async method which return ElementArrayFinder for E2E tests

Tags: async-await, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a class where I want to make a async method which will return ElementArrayFinder. I need exactly this type, not ElementFinder[] because my waiters based on it and I can wait element which isn't present now in DOM. Below you can find a simple example of the structure. At row 'return this.collection;' i have an error:

> [ts]
>   Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'ElementArrayFinder'.
>    Property 'browser_' is missing in type 'any[]'.

I tried to cast result in a different way and tried to use Promise.resolve, but no success. Could somebody help me with this case?

```
export class Test {
    private grid1: ElementFinder;
    private grid2: ElementFinder;

    get collection1(): ElementArrayFinder {
        return this.grid1
            .element(by.css('tbody'))
            .all(by.tagName('tr'));
    }

    get collection2(): ElementArrayFinder {
        return this.grid2
            .element(by.css('tbody'))
            .all(by.tagName('tr'));
    }


    public async getCollection(): Promise<ElementArrayFinder> {

        if (await this.collection.count() === 0) {
            return this.collection1;
        }
        return this.collection2;
    }
}
```

### Bug report

- Node Version: `v8.2.1`
- Protractor Version: `5.2.0`

Comment: Did you try without the `grid`s? ... `return this.element(by.css('tbody')).all(by.css('tr'));` ... I'm not sure, if you want/need to include an `ElementFinder` into your function here.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The result will be the same, unfortunately. The reason is described in solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in file element.d.ts file.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the elements represented by the ElementArrayFinder. The input
 * function is passed to the resulting promise, which resolves to an
 * array of ElementFinders.
 *
 * @alias element.all(locator).then(thenFunction)
 * @view
 * <ul class="items">
 *   <li>First</li>
 *   <li>Second</li>
 *   <li>Third</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @example
 * element.all(by.css('.items li')).then(function(arr) {
 *   expect(arr.length).toEqual(3);
 * });
 *
 * // Or using the shortcut $$() notation instead of element.all(by.css()):
 *
 * $$('.items li').then(function(arr) {
 *   expect(arr.length).toEqual(3);
 * });
 *
 * @param {function(Array.<ElementFinder>)} fn
 * @param {function(Error)} errorFn
 *
 * @returns {!webdriver.promise.Promise} A promise which will resolve to
 *     an array of ElementFinders represented by the ElementArrayFinder.
 */
then<T>(fn?: (value: ElementFinder[] | any[]) => T | wdpromise.IThenable<T>, errorFn?: (error: any) => any): wdpromise.Promise<T>;
```

Based on this documentation ElementArrayFinder type is resolved by .then to the ElementFinder[]. That's why I cannot create method which return ElementArrayFinder type in promise, but can create method which simply return ElementArrayFinder type.